How to deal with performance evaluation of software engineers by non-experts in the field
I previously have had an experience where my performance as an engineer was evaluated by a non-engineer (forgive the ferocity of the post, I'm still mad)
I'm finding that it is remarkably common for software engineers to have their performance evaluated by non-engineers, particularly in game programming.
If this is the reality we have to grapple with, how can a software engineer get on in an industry seemingly unwilling to adequately respect the craft and skill of software engineering?
How do you deal with a non-technical manager as a software engineer in a way that you can keep your job?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Learn to get along with non-coders, that's how the world works.  Since we don't know what your feedback was & don't know you anyway, we can't really give you feedback on it, but recognize that workplaces have hundred of things you need to do that have nothing to do with technical skill.

Performance evaluations should be fairly objective if your company is doing it right. Expectations and goals should be clearly laid out, so that your evaluations can be based on whether you met those. A non-technical person can do that just as easily as a technical person.  I read your blog post (was this question just a way to drive clicks??) and there wasn't much there that was about being non-technical. Example 1 was they said you weren't completing tasks in a sprint, and you claim you did the most tasks on the team. That's a completely objective measuring stick so there must be a breakdown of communication somewhere. Also, it is incredibly common for managers to have different technical skills from their reports, or none at all - they have managerial skills instead which includes systems to evaluate their employeees with. Learn the system so you can advocate for yourself within in. By the way, wild to start your post by apologizing for the ferocity of it and then claim it was devoid of emotion.

I hate to break it to you. Coders are actually tradespeople.
You/we aren't Jackson Pollock or Andy Warhol or Leonardo da Vinci. We aren't artists.
Our work is much more quantifiable.
That being said, it doesn't excuse a performance evaluation without meaninful metrics.
People tend to perform to the metrics that they are measured.
If there weren't metrics, consider suggesting them to the management team.

It will always be the case that someone who does not understand how something is done, will not be able to reasonably effectively make an assessment of whether that task was performed well or not.
Think about a gymnastics competition. Although everyone is free to watch, everyone who is not a technical expert in gymnastics is invariably quite surprised by the scores when they are held up by the judges. That’s because viewers who are non-experts in gymnastics do not have a very good semblance of what it means to perform well at the sport.

According to the video linked above, there is 200-page manual describing criteria against which excellent performance at gymnastics is determined. Someone who does not study that manual will not be able to score the performer reasonably well, against the established standards that define what it means to do well at that sport.

Computer Science/Computer Programming has well more than 200 pages written about it that describe what it means to do well at it.
If you haven't studied any good portion of those pages, then you are not going to do a reasonable job at determining whether a software engineer has performed well at software engineering or not.
Many of the posts above/below are really expressing a kind of ruinous empathy for people who are trying to or are already doing a job for which they are not qualified nor capable.
If you want your performance evaluation to be done by someone who has deep technical knowledge, you should ensure that will be the case at the interview stage, and make it a condition to accept the position.
If you have a non-technical manager in a technical position now, even if they haven't started any campaigns/warfare where they mission to call you inadequate yet, you should search for another job where the manager would be a technical person.
At least then, arguing that you are competent at the job will not be an utter exercise in futility.

As I mentioned earlier an engineering job is not a coding competition...and it's not comparable to a gymnastics competition, or any other competition where someone judges who is the "best". Jobs don't work like that.

@mattfreake This is not necessarily comparative, but in capitalism, the workforce is actually a competition. The point is, to know if someone performed well at the sport of gymnastics, you have to master a 200 page manual that defines what it means to perform well at that sport.

@mattfreake The workforce is not a welfare program, where you are entitled to a paycheck simply because you went to the right school for it
